# How to configure apache proxy ssl foward JBoss?

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss

I have configured jboss https below(standalone.xml):

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="https" key-alias="jboss" password="123456" certificate-key-file="${jboss.home.dir}/keystores/jeap6.keystore"/>
</connector>
```

and I can visit https://ip:8443

I also configured apache server https so I can visit https://ip.
Here is a part of httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ProxyPass /xxx http://192.168.1.188:8080/xxx
    ProxyPassReverse /xxx http://192.168.1.188:8080/xxx
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I configured

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ProxyPass /xxx https://192.168.1.188:8443/xxx
    ProxyPassReverse /xxx https://192.168.1.188:8443/xxx
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

It doesn't work.
How to resolve it?

log like this:

```
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:51 2015] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.187 for ServerName
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:52 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:52 2015] [notice] Server built: Jul 10 2013 01:52:12
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:52 2015] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3884
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.187 for ServerName
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.187 for ServerName
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [notice] Child 3884: Child process is running
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [notice] Child 3884: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [notice] Child 3884: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [notice] Child 3884: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Mon Apr 20 15:17:54 2015] [notice] Child 3884: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Apr 20 15:18:16 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.188] SSL Proxy requested for www.xxx.com:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Mon Apr 20 15:18:16 2015] [error] proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 192.168.1.188:8443 (192.168.1.188)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pass on the error in the log files. If the keystores are using self-signed keys, you will need to import the public key's to get the handshake to succeed.

Comment: How to export the public key actually? Now I only have jeap6.keystore on jboss. Thanks.